# Error in importing Pylab

Tags: python, import, matplotlib, enthought

I am trying to import Pylab using the `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. However I received an error message below. Does anyone have a fix for this? I'm using Enthought's distribution, which uses IPython 0.12.

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-eff513f636fd> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     21 from matplotlib.cbook import dedent, silent_list, is_string_like, is_numlike
     22 from matplotlib import docstring
---> 23 from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
     24 from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
     25 from matplotlib.image import imread as _imread

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in <module>()
     16 import artist
     17 from artist import Artist, allow_rasterization
---> 18 from axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
     19 from cbook import flatten, allequal, Stack, iterable, is_string_like
     20 import _image

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py in <module>()
     12 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     13 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 14 import matplotlib.axis as maxis
     15 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     16 import matplotlib.collections as mcoll

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in <module>()
      8 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
      9 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 10 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     11 import matplotlib.lines as mlines
     12 import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
     50 import matplotlib
     51 from matplotlib import afm
---> 52 from matplotlib import ft2font
     53 from matplotlib import rcParams, get_configdir
     54 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so, 2): Library         not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Edit: The output of `ls -ltr /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/`:

```
total 19800
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   44538 Sep 24 21:21 widgets.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    5035 Sep 24 21:21 units.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   11537 Sep 24 21:21 type1font.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   77154 Sep 24 21:21 transforms.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    7098 Sep 24 21:21 tight_layout.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    3839 Sep 24 21:21 tight_bbox.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   51195 Sep 24 21:21 ticker.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   15516 Sep 24 21:21 textpath.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   69526 Sep 24 21:21 text.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   22703 Sep 24 21:21 texmanager.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   16868 Sep 24 21:21 table.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   17723 Sep 24 21:21 spines.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   14316 Sep 24 21:21 scale.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   40573 Sep 24 21:21 sankey.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   25707 Sep 24 21:21 rcsetup.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   40599 Sep 24 21:21 quiver.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   92531 Sep 24 21:21 pyplot.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  143924 Sep 24 21:21 pyparsing.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   11742 Sep 24 21:21 pylab.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    6826 Sep 24 21:21 patheffects.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   24453 Sep 24 21:21 path.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  133545 Sep 24 21:21 patches.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   50156 Sep 24 21:21 offsetbox.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel     785 Sep 24 21:21 mpl.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  100604 Sep 24 21:21 mlab.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  109731 Sep 24 21:21 mathtext.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   23594 Sep 24 21:21 markers.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   38180 Sep 24 21:21 lines.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   20098 Sep 24 21:21 legend_handler.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   35251 Sep 24 21:21 legend.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   46614 Sep 24 21:21 image.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    6564 Sep 24 21:21 hatch.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   16092 Sep 24 21:21 gridspec.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    6429 Sep 24 21:21 fontconfig_pattern.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   43749 Sep 24 21:21 font_manager.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   23033 Sep 24 21:21 finance.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   50232 Sep 24 21:21 figure.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   32575 Sep 24 21:21 dviread.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    3769 Sep 24 21:21 docstring.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   40070 Sep 24 21:21 dates.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   54477 Sep 24 21:21 contour.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    2832 Sep 24 21:21 container.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   44186 Sep 24 21:21 colors.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   34547 Sep 24 21:21 colorbar.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   45282 Sep 24 21:21 collections.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    9508 Sep 24 21:21 cm.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   59573 Sep 24 21:21 cbook.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   12895 Sep 24 21:21 blocking_input.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   16237 Sep 24 21:21 bezier.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   94652 Sep 24 21:21 backend_bases.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   72371 Sep 24 21:21 axis.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  301792 Sep 24 21:21 axes.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   37279 Sep 24 21:21 artist.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   19948 Sep 24 21:21 animation.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   15422 Sep 24 21:21 afm.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    3275 Sep 24 21:21 _pylab_helpers.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   89917 Sep 24 21:21 _mathtext_data.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   88432 Sep 24 21:21 _cm.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   33452 Sep 24 21:21 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  844488 Sep 24 21:21 ft2font.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  152904 Sep 24 21:21 ttconv.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel   53672 Sep 24 21:21 _cntr.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel   35020 Sep 24 21:21 nxutils.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  161740 Sep 24 21:21 _delaunay.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  741008 Sep 24 21:21 _path.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  693588 Sep 24 21:21 _tri.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 scott  wheel  828348 Sep 24 21:21 _image.so copy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  828348 Sep 24 21:21 _image.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel  488096 Sep 24 21:22 _png.so
drwxr-xr-x   7 root   wheel     238 Sep 24 21:22 mpl-data
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   44944 Sep 24 21:22 widgets.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    5808 Sep 24 21:22 units.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   11090 Sep 24 21:22 type1font.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  12 root   wheel     408 Sep 24 21:22 tri
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   91307 Sep 24 21:22 transforms.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    6061 Sep 24 21:22 tight_layout.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    4172 Sep 24 21:22 tight_bbox.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   57906 Sep 24 21:22 ticker.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   14645 Sep 24 21:22 textpath.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   67364 Sep 24 21:22 text.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   19813 Sep 24 21:22 texmanager.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  50 root   wheel    1700 Sep 24 21:22 tests
drwxr-xr-x  11 root   wheel     374 Sep 24 21:22 testing
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   16758 Sep 24 21:22 table.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   15471 Sep 24 21:22 spines.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  12 root   wheel     408 Sep 24 21:22 sphinxext
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   19505 Sep 24 21:22 scale.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   26862 Sep 24 21:22 sankey.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   22428 Sep 24 21:22 rcsetup.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   35530 Sep 24 21:22 quiver.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   91567 Sep 24 21:22 pyplot.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  144868 Sep 24 21:22 pyparsing.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   13151 Sep 24 21:22 pylab.pyc
drwxr-xr-x   8 root   wheel     272 Sep 24 21:22 projections
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    7714 Sep 24 21:22 patheffects.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   22967 Sep 24 21:22 path.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  134328 Sep 24 21:22 patches.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   54567 Sep 24 21:22 offsetbox.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    1175 Sep 24 21:22 mpl.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  105969 Sep 24 21:22 mlab.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  109167 Sep 24 21:22 mathtext.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   25276 Sep 24 21:22 markers.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   41185 Sep 24 21:22 lines.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   18782 Sep 24 21:22 legend_handler.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   28941 Sep 24 21:22 legend.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   44466 Sep 24 21:22 image.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    9038 Sep 24 21:22 hatch.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   14893 Sep 24 21:22 gridspec.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    6491 Sep 24 21:22 fontconfig_pattern.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   40188 Sep 24 21:22 font_manager.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   19865 Sep 24 21:22 finance.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   51123 Sep 24 21:22 figure.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   33935 Sep 24 21:22 dviread.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    5278 Sep 24 21:22 docstring.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  10 root   wheel     340 Sep 24 21:22 delaunay
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   43998 Sep 24 21:22 dates.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   46848 Sep 24 21:22 contour.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    4997 Sep 24 21:22 container.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   43736 Sep 24 21:22 colors.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   32285 Sep 24 21:22 colorbar.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   46694 Sep 24 21:22 collections.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   10966 Sep 24 21:22 cm.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   71936 Sep 24 21:22 cbook.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   14396 Sep 24 21:22 blocking_input.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   14524 Sep 24 21:22 bezier.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  59 root   wheel    2006 Sep 24 21:22 backends
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   98700 Sep 24 21:22 backend_bases.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   68984 Sep 24 21:22 axis.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  268555 Sep 24 21:22 axes.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   40988 Sep 24 21:22 artist.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   15092 Sep 24 21:22 animation.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   16956 Sep 24 21:22 afm.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel    4467 Sep 24 21:22 _pylab_helpers.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   64647 Sep 24 21:22 _mathtext_data.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   81690 Sep 24 21:22 _cm.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   32767 Sep 24 21:22 __init__.pyc
```

And the output of `ls -ltr /opt/local/lib/`:

```
ls: /opt/local/lib/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You're importing the from the system Python's site-packages directory (/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages) rather than EPD's site-packages directory (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages).

This is likely due to .pth files in your system site-packages directory. Those files are causing the system site-packages directory to get added to your PYTHONPATH when running EPD's Python (look at sys.path to confirm) Delete or otherwise remove those files and you should be able to import from the matplotlib that comes with EPD.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your font caches and trying again:

`rm -rf  ~/.matplotlib/*cache*`

Alternatively, would you be able to provide the output of

`ls -ltr /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/`

and

`/opt/local/lib/`

Comment: Done! I also tried the `rm` command, but it didn't do anything.